# When should I add "The" and when is it ok to drop it?

Tags: articles

I'm developing a messaging platform for a new foundation. Let's say, their name is "The ABCD Foundation." 
I'm trying to craft some guidelines about when they should refer to themselves as "ABCD" and when as "The ABCD Foundation." I'm trying to explain why it varies, and I'm not sure what grammatical principle I should reference.

For example: "The ABCD Foundation was established by..." seems more correct than "ABCD was established by" BUT "decades of experience have equipped ABCD's team with" sounds fine and "decades of experience have equipped The ABCD Foundation's team with" sounds too long.

In addition to attempting to keep some consistency, I feel there is a correct and incorrect way of doing this. Maybe I'm wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Kinda depends on what you found in the research you did.

Comment: There must be numerous duplicates, some are in the panel on the right.

Comment: "ABCD" is an abbreviated term of reference for "The ABCD Foundation", as is "The Foundation", "their", "it" etc. You should mix and match the phrases according to what sounds right in the context rather than slavishly following a rule of "the first mention in a paragraph should be the full name then the contracted form thereafter for the rest of the paragraph" etc. I'd probably aim to use the full name about 5% of the time, for impact. As such I'm not sure how this question can be objectively answered; it's highly contextual

Comment: There aren't really any rules for when to use "The" in an organization name, it tends to be the organization's choice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first time you mention it, spell out the full name. After that, you can shorten it to ABCD whenever you like.

When you just refer to it as *the foundation*, don't capitalize it.

NOTE: Use either *OK* or *okay*.  Don't use *ok*. It's not okay. Okay?